# Prometheus query comparing different metrics with same set of labels

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus

I'm trying to monitor if a queue in rabbitmq:

1. has messages
2. does not have a consumer
3. is not called .*_retry

If a queue matches all three, I want to create an alert.

The individual metrics are no problem to find but I cannot comprehend how I am going to AND the different metrics in one query, grouping them by a set of labels (ie. instance, queue).

Is this even possible?

I'm using the latest version of prometheus and scraping rabbitmq via it's built-in prometheus metrics plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you have two metrics from different exporters:

```
probe_success              => Blackbox exporter
node_memory_MemTotal_bytes => Node exporter
```

Suppose they have two common labels: "instance" and "group".

If you use the following query:

```
sum by (instance, group) (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)>20000000000 and sum by (instance, group) (probe_success)==1
```

You'll get the instance+group with memory>20G and is UP.

See more info about logical operators in Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't realise that ANDing a set of those queries actually carried over the grouping of the labels.